# A variable plane at distance $3p$ from the origin cuts the coordinate axes at $A$, $B$, $C$. Show that the locus of $\triangle ABC$'s centroid is ...

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

> A variable plane which remains at a constant distance 3p from the origin cuts the coordinate axes at A, B, C. Show that the locus of the centroid of $\triangle ABC$ is
> $$\frac {1}{x^2}+ \frac {1}{y^2} + \frac {1}{z^2} = \frac {1}{p^2}$$

**My work**:

As it is given that there are equal intercepts cut at A , B & C so we get (a,0,0),(0,b,0),(0,0,c)

So this plane is at a distance 3p from (0,0,0)

I *understood* this much ,Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Users on this site like to answer those questions where the questioner put some effort by showing their work or adding their thoughts about the problem. As your post is lacking your attempt, there are possibilities that your question will attract some downvotes and may even be closed. To prevent that, please edit your question and provide context.[Refer to this text to know how to ask a good question here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/1010982). We are not here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'll give you some hints!*

**Hint 1:** Start by assuming the equation of plane be $\dfrac{x}{a} + \dfrac{y}{b} +  \dfrac{z}{c} = 1$ where $a, b$ and $c$ are intercepts on plane on $x, y$ and $z$ axis respectively.

**Hint 2:** Now find the distance of the plane from the origin.

**Hint 3:** Centroid of triangle will be $\left(\dfrac{a}{3}, \dfrac{b}{3}, \dfrac{c}{3}\right)$ let it be $(x,y, z)$

Now establish the relationship.

Comment: I got the relation now